# Why doesn't this thunk update the store?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I have created a thunk that dispatches a bunch of different actions:

```
export function resetEverything() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return Promise.all([
      dispatch(updateCurrentColor('blue')),
      dispatch(updateCurrentTypeChoice('hot')),
      dispatch(updateData('fish', {})),
      dispatch(updateData('giraffes', {})),
      dispatch(updateData('elephants', {})),
      dispatch(updateData('zebras', {})),
    ]).then(() => console.log('resetEverything called'));
  };
}
```

These actions are also used in the application individually. Individually called, they work fine; the store is updated with the payloads.

However, in this batch operation, all of the actions are dispatched, the console shows "resetEverything called", and even when I look through the Redux extension in Chrome, each of the actions are dispatched with the same structure (with different payload, naturally). But...when I look at the Diff it says `(states are equal)` and sure enough, examining the State>Tree shows that the store keys haven't been updated at all.

Why isn't this working? Why are the dispatched actions being ignored?

Reducer:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_CURRENT_COLOR:
      return update(state, { currentColor: { $set: action.payload } });
    case UPDATE_CURRENT_TYPE_CHOICE:
      return update(state, { currentTypeChoice: { $set: action.payload } });
    case UPDATE_DATA:
      return update(state, { data: { [action.payload.property]: { $merge: action.payload.dataObject } } });
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we have a look at your reducers?

Comment: @AlexandreGUIDET I just added it above. (The individual actions when invoked seem to work just fine at updating the store's state)

Comment: @zahabba Have you logged anything in the reducer while testing?  It is possible that you can see the actions being fired in the redux dev tools but they are somehow not getting to the reducer.

Comment: @bmartin I did try that; the individual/component actions were firing just as they should (with "emptyish" payloads) but the state would remain unchanged.